# JavaScript function not getting called from onclick

Tags: javascript, jsf, icefaces

I am trying to call a JavaScript function from icefaces check box component like this:

```
 <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{reportBean.selected}"      onclick="toggleSelectAllRows()" />
```

Then JavaScript code is :

```
<script>
  function toggleSelectAllRows() {
    alert("Entered selectAll");
  } 

  } 
</script>
```

But after checking the check box, the alert box is not getting displayed. What can be the reason?

Comment: what is the raw HTML generated ?

Comment: parenthesis mismatch in javascript function

Comment: I would start with onclick="alert('test')"; to see if your event handler works like expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really your JavaScript code, there is a `}` too much at the end, thus preventing your JavaScript from being parsed (and executed).

```
<script>
function toggleSelectAllRows() {
  alert("Entered selectAll");
} 
</script>
```